# Allow migration of suitable hardware questions to the Hardware Recommendations Stack site

Tags: feature-request, migration, close-reasons

There was a site proposed in [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) called [Hardware Recommendations](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/). It is now in public beta and I think it would be helpful to migrate and redirect users with hardware questions to this site instead of just closing their questions.

My request is to add this site in the options when closing a question via

> This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network

Comment: Which one would you replace? (Considering we don't add beta sites on that list in the first place)

Comment: I don't want to be critical, but... The site is currently only 71% answered. Do you really think they're better off sent away rather than redirected toward a problem-based question here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Public beta's too early for migration anyway, and considering the two recommendations sites are *unique* in their scope and previous experience as a moderator on software recommendations I'm not sure this is the greatest idea.

If someone asks a question that's *clearly* and *explicitly* off topic, its probably a clear sign that the question needs some adult supervision.

*If* a question's clearly on topic there there and *excellent* - meeting their quality standards in every way, and you flag it for moderation, chances are no one will yell at you. We'll be a little confused why it was asked here.

Quite often though, the process we've always had in place - suggesting people drop into chat, talking to them about what they're trying to do, and more recently, passing them on to hardware recommendations if needed, seems to work well.

In short, its a *terrible* idea for now while HR's still in the beta stages.

If we're discussing re-jigging our migration targets, it would probably in the future, and we'd need to decide one of the current ones is no longer needed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. After reading the answer and the comments, I can see how it wouldn't be suitable at this point in time. Perhaps it may be an option in the future.

Comment: Typically Beta sites are left to their own vinces, if they make it, only then would we migrate a hardware/software recomendatio question.  Besides if it's closed here they can always ask it in the proper place...themselves

Answer (score 3):

9-ish years later, and I am revisiting this…

Oftentimes I leave a fairly generic comment, via “Other - add a comment”, as follows:

> “I’m voting to close this question because it is better suited for the [Hardware Recommendations SE](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) site.”

But what about adding the [Hardware Recommendations SE](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) the list of items under “What site does this question belong on?”

If any migration targets should be rethought, I would recommend removing the [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com) migration target since — in my experience — is rarely used whereas [Hardware Recommendations](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com) is used regularly by me.